How do I bind data automatically in controller action in .NET 5?
I'm very inexperienced with .NET so please bear with me.
I try to send a post request:
var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "YearValue", Convert.ToString( txtYear.Value) },
        { "Season", Convert.ToString( txtSeason.Value )},
        { "TestType", Convert.ToString( cboExamType.SelectedValue) },
        { "EmployeeID", Convert.ToString( _login.user.EmployeeID) },
        { "LoginName",_login.user.Code }
    });
postData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var req = client.PostAsync(url, postData);

and receive it:
[HttpPost("tests")]
public IActionResult Tests(int YearValue,int Season,int TestType,int EmployeeID,string LoginName)

which doesn't work because it doesn't correctly bind the data  automatically, I had to add [FromForm] to each parameter individually for it to work.
So my question is: Is there a way to make the controller action automatically bind the data correctly or tell it that all the parameters are [FromForm]? Much obliged.

Create a class containing those parameters. And change your action method to public IActionResult Tests([FromForm] TestsInput model)

The easiest option would be to create a type to hold the data, make it the parameter of the action and mark it with corresponding attribute:
// C# 10 syntax, for .NET 5 create a simple class with auto-properties
public record TestModel(int YearValue, int Season, int TestType, int EmployeeID, string LoginName);

[HttpPost("tests")]
public IActionResult Tests([FromForm] TestModel input)
{
    // ...
}

See the Model Binding in ASP.NET Core doc.
